# jQuery : nested loops

Tags: jquery

Please help, I need simple AJAX call to populate ddlist as in the following example:

```
**United Kingdom**
   *(London
   Birmingham
   Bristol
   Leeds)*
**France**
   *(Paris
   Lille
   Calais)*
**Spain**
   *(Barcelona
   Real Madrid)*
```

I have tried

```
$.each(data.d.country, function(index, item) {
  $("#ddlist").append("<option />").text(item);
     $.each(item, function(newIndex, newItem) {
        $("#ddlist").append("<option />").text(newItem);
      });
  });
```

Comment: "$.each($(data.d.country"
Is that a typo? You never close that parenthesis.

Comment: Are you able to create a simple jsfiddle with the sample data?

Comment: yes its a typo thanks

Comment: I'm not seeing what this have to do with ajax.  But, seeing the actual data structure would help.

Comment: AJAX is calling web method, which returns countries, and for each country there is a dictionary of id + city name

Comment: Is the data along the lines of data.d.country = [{"United Kingdom" : [{"id":1,"city":"London"}, {"id":2, "city":"Birmingham"}]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how the ajax returns the countries/cities objects but here is an example how you can create that select options

```
var countries = ["United Kingdom",
                 "France",
                 "Spain"];
var cities = [["London",
               "Birmingham",
               "Bristol",
               "Leeds"], 
              ["Paris",
               "Lille",
               "Calais"],
              ["Barcelona",
               "Real Madrid"]
             ];

$(countries).each(function(key, val){
    $("#result").append('<optgroup label="'+val+'">');
    $(cities[key]).each(function(k, v){
        $("#result").append('<option>'+v+'</option>');
    });
    $("#result").append('</optgroup>');
});
```

EXAMPLE: http://jsfiddle.net/kC75w/

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this plugin:
http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=ComboTree&theme=default&dir=ltr&pitem=